# Unix script to compare a timestamp with current time

Tags: shell, unix, unix-timestamp

This is my first journey into the realm of Unix scripting and I'm not sure how to go about this.  Ill be querying a DB and pulling out a timestamp.  What I need to do is take that timestamp (in the awesome format of `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`) and if its more than 10 minutes old, return a 1 else return 0.

Again, I have essentially 0 experience with this type of scripting (background is in C++ and C#) so if you guys don't mind a little more explanation I'd be grateful - I want to learn how it works too.

Thanks!

Comment: perl, python, ruby.. any preference?

Comment: Use the formatting of the `date` utility to format the current time plus 10*60 s into the same format as the DB gives then do a simple string comparison. Trivial in Bash, but I side with Karoly any preferences? ... :)

Comment: @Venk: uhm? So we are asking which interpreter he'd prefer ... what other is 'unix' than some term for a number of quite different environments adhering to some standard or a trademark, depending on your view? :)

Comment: YYYYMMDDHHMMSS *is* an awesome timestamp format.  My answer below shows why.  Not only can you do math with it, but it sorts naturally.

Comment: Do you have GNU Date?  If so, you can lexicographically compare your timestamp with the output of `date -u -d '-10 minutes' +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` (the `-u` assumes that your database timestamp is in UTC, which I'd advise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $dbtimestamp has the timestamp returned from the database, but I'm hard-coding it here.

```
dbtimestamp=20120306142400

secondsDiff=$(( `date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'` - $dbtimestamp ))
if [ $secondsDiff -gt 600 ] 
then
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: This is treating YmdHMS strings as they were decimal numbers.
$(( 20120306150000 - 20120306145959 )) returns 4041, not 1

Comment: Yes, that's why the very next line compares the difference in seconds to 600 (10 minutes) and then returns 0 or 1.

Comment: The "best" answer is wrong : dbtimestamp=20120306142400
currenttimestamp=20120306143001 The arithmetic difference is : 601 but between the 2 timestamp, the are only 6 min and 1 sec :-/

Comment: @dj_segfault what djjeck meant is that the two timestamps he used are only 1 second appart, but `secondsDiff` will have the value 4041, which is greater than 600 and thus will return 1 although decidedly less than 10 minutes have passed. It is even worse when passing midnight more so when switching months or years. Also, when you compare against 600 you check if the the difference is greater than 6 minutes not 10 minutes. **Conclusion**: as it is now, **the answer is not correct**. It provides wrong answers in many cases when the difference is less than 10 minutes.

Comment: I thought that this wrong answer could be rescued by adding `1000` to `dbtimestamp`, and then comparing against the current time.  That won't work when the minutes roll over (e.g. 00:55:01 should wrap to 01:05:01, not 00:65:01), so this approach appears to be doomed.

Answer (score 7):

The way your tools work depends on the flavour of Unix you use.  The following should work in Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OSX, etc.

```
#!/bin/sh

sample="${1:-20120306131701}"

if ! expr "$sample" : '[0-9]\{14\}$' >/dev/null; then
  echo "ERROR: unknown date format" >&2
  exit 65
fi

case $(uname -s) in
  *BSD|Darwin)
    # The BSD date command allows you to specify an input format.
    epoch=$(date -jf '%Y%m%d%H%M%S' "$sample" '+%s')
    ;;
  Linux)
    # No input format in Linux, so rewrite date to something '-d' will parse
    tmpdate="$(echo "$sample" | sed -r 's/(.{8})(..)(..)(..)/\1 \2:\3:\4/')"
    epoch=$(date -d "$tmpdate" '+%s')
    ;;
  *)
    echo "ERROR: I don't know how to do this in $(uname -s)." >&2
    exit 69
    ;;
esac

now=$(date '+%s')

# And with the provided datetime and current time as integers, it's MATH time.
if [ $((now - epoch)) -gt 600 ]; then
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Note that this is a `/bin/sh` script, for the sake of portability, so it doesn't take advantage of bash-isms you may be used to in Linux, in particular `[[ ... ]]` and heretext to read variables.

Oh, and I'm assuming that you meant "exit value" when you said "return value". A return value would be the result of a function, but what I've written above is a stand-alone script.

Note that this may not understand timestamps in the future, nor does it take timezone into consideration.  If that's important to you, you should, er, consider it.  :-)  And test in your environment.